# PLS-00201: identifier 'schema.cursorname' must be declared

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, plsql, odp.net

I know there are a couple of other questions on here with the exact same issue, but I am 100% positive I don't have any type of permissions issue. The procedure executes fine from the query editor, but for some reason I can't get this proc to execute from a very simple ASP.net page. I should note this is my first attempt at creating an Oracle Proc.

Here is my code that calls the proc (just trying to call it and force results into the label)

```
    string oradb = "connection string here";

    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);

    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = "x.GETCURSORS";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    OracleParameter ACTNUM = new OracleParameter();
    ACTNUM.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Decimal;
    ACTNUM.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    ACTNUM.Value ="12345";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(ACTNUM);

    OracleParameter REJECTS_C = new OracleParameter();
    REJECTS_C.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor;
    REJECTS_C.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(REJECTS_C);


    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        OracleDataReader objReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        Label3.Text = objReader.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label3.Text = string.Format("Exception: {0}", ex.ToString());

    }
```

Package specification:

```
PACKAGE "x"."REJECTS_DATA" IS

PROCEDURE "GETCURSORS" (
"ACTNUM" IN NUMBER, 
"REJECTS_C" OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);

 END "REJECTS_DATA";
```

Package body:

```
PACKAGE BODY "x"."REJECTS_DATA" IS

PROCEDURE "GETCURSORS" (
"ACTNUM" IN NUMBER, 
"REJECTS_C" OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS

BEGIN

OPEN REJECTS_C FOR SELECT * FROM x.a
WHERE  x.a.ACCOUNT = ACTNUM;

END "GETCURSORS";

END "REJECTS_DATA";
```

Comment: In the package specification and definition, you are using case-sensitive identifiers and using a lower-case `"x"` for the schema name.  In your C# code, you are not using case-sensitive identifiers.  Is that simply an artifact of preparing the question or is that an issue in your actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the schema name is `X`, the package name is `REJECTS_DATA`, and the procedure name is `GETCURSORS`, at a minimum, the command would need to be

```
cmd.CommandText = "x.REJECTS_DATA.GETCURSORS";
```

If you are actually using case-sensitive identifers in PL/SQL (which I would strongly suggest avoiding), you would need to use case-sensitive identifiers in the procedure name as well.

Comment: The x is just lowercase because I edited the table name out for posting purposes. Adding the package name worked. Ouch that was simple.

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same issue in our code and had to keep SCHEMA_NAME out of our proc call in C#, i.e. PACKAGE_NAME.PROC_NAME. We resolved this by creating a Synonym in the database with the SCHEMA_NAME